# Prevent direct access for all pages, not even when clicking the navbar href of the page

Tags: php, reactjs, laravel

In order to prevent direct url access, I addes this code at the very top of my PHP files.

```
    <?php
    if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='GET' && realpath(__FILE__) == realpath( 
      $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] ) ) {        
    header( 'HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden', TRUE, 403 );
    die( header( 'location: index.php' ) );
         }
        ?>
```

It works, but the problem is that it functions too when I click on the page href in the navbar. So how to prevent that?

Let me put it differently. I have a navbar with different pages lings, after I disabled the direct access by putting the code in all pages, the access is denied even when I click on the page line in the navbar of the website. I do not want that, I want access to be denied only when user writes a direct path to the path in the URL search bar.

Comment: Your question does'nt have enough informations. Kindly elaborate your question.

Comment: Let me put it differently. I have a navbar with different pages lings, after I disabled the direct access by putting the code in all pages, the access is denied even when I click on the page line in the navbar of the website. I do not want that, I want access to be denied only when user writes a direct path to the path in the URL search bar.

Answer (score 0):

It cannot be directly done, Since you cannot detect whether the user is typed the url or it came by clicking the navbar.

So what you can do is, You can set a flag in the browser's local storage. And only if the flag is there in the localstorage. Allow the page to load. Otherwise do not allow the page to load.

You also need to remove the flag from the localstorage each and every time the page loading is completed and set the flag If user clicks in the navbar.

So, If the user directly types in the url. The flag will not be available in the localstorage and you can redirect whereever you want or you can show the unauthorised page. This way you can identify whether the url is directly entered in the browser or by clicking the navbar.

The easiest way is you can do it through javascript.

```
<script>
   // For setting the flag value
   localStorage.setItem('flag', 'true');

   // For retrieving the flag value
   let localFlag = localStorage.getItem('flag');

   // For removing the flag value
   localStorage.removeItem("flag"); 
</script>;
```